# Why can't Pycharm find remote python3.9?

Tags: python-3

I am using pycharm for remote development with rpi3, when I try to run my code I get the error from pycharm that it can't find a file: (IGNORE the X)

```
Error running 'test': Cannot run program "sftp:\\pi@192.168.XXX.XX:22\usr\bin\python3.9" (in directory "C:\Users\XXXX XXXXX\PycharmProjects\Example\tests"): CreateProcess error=2
```

Both files are present, I can SSH fine, upload files, connection is fine.
Python3.9 is installed:

```
python3.9 is already the newest version (3.9.2-1).
```

I have no idea why it won't run. I am running RPI OS Lite 64 Bit.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer just as I posted the question.

1. Go to "Run/Debug Configuration"
2. Copy or remember the original script path
3. Empty the Script Path
4. Apply
5. Enter/reselect the original script path
6. Apply
7. Profit

Its a bug, makes no sense but works.